# How to make a dropdown menu show beyond the borders of a card in Materialize

Tags: drop-down-menu, materialize

I have a Materialize card with a dropdown menu in the top right corner. However, when clicking the dropdown button, the menu shows but the menu content doesn't go beyond the border of the card:

```
<ul id='myDropdown-menu' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="card white">
  <div class="card-content grey-text text-darken-4">
    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title</span>
      <a id="myDropdown" class='btn-floating waves-effect waves-light transparent right' href='#' data-activates='myDropdown-menu'><i class="material-icons blue-grey-text text-darken-4">more_vert</i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the dropdown menu go beyond the borders of a card?

http://jsfiddle.net/6sjLbrht/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be an `overflow: hidden` on the `.card` class which is preventing the menu from appearing outside the borders of the card. By adding the following style in your own stylesheet you can overcome this is

```
.card {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

I've updated the JSFiddle to illustrate the fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/6sjLbrht/1/